# Undefined index: learner_id

Tags: php

I have made this codes that registers the students using their learner id. And of course i wanted to make sure that there will be no duplication of learner id as students registered.These are my codes.

```
$select_query="select student_id from student_information where learner_id = '$learner_id'";
$result_set = mysql_query($select_query,$link_id);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
    $flag="exists";
    header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag&student_id=$student_id");
    die();
}
else{
    /*
        This block is used to insert the learners record in database 
        if the student_id is not yet registered in the database. 
    */
    mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0 ");
    if(mysql_error() != null){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Everytime there is a duplication of learner id. I am using this code on the other page for notifying me that the learner id exist already.

```
>This Learner Id( <?php $_GET['learner_id'] ?> ) already exists. Please try again with another Learner Id.</td>
```

The log in page give me notice

This Learner Id(Notice: Undefined index: learner_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\Student_login.php on line 61
) already exists. Please try again with another Learner Id.

How do i fix this one. Please advise.

Comment: Well ... you have `student_id` query param in the header() call. And then you try to use `learned_id` from $_GET ...

Comment: thanks i didnt see that. you have a point. i followed your advise but still didnt work. i think there is still missing

Answer (score 1):

In your first program where you get $learner_id. Are you declared or it is constant?

Did you use the below code above select statement.

```
$learner_id=$_GET['learner_id']
//or
$learner_id=$_POST['learner_id']
```

Comment: what's that suppose to mean? sorry i am new in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's a `_GET`, you can't be sure it's always there - unlike a constant.

```
if( array_key_exists('learner_id', $_GET) ) {
    $_GET['learner_id'] = ctype_digit( (string) $_GET['learner_id']) ? (int) $_GET['learner_id'] : 0;
} else {
    $_GET['learner_id'] = 0;
}
```

- Check it exists

  - Check it doesn't contain any dodgy characters
  - If it does, reset the value to `0`
- If it doesn't exist, create it with a value of `0`
- `0` value will of course fail - as you won't have index `0` in your database ;)
- **Tip:** Never trust user input. Validate and sanitize data input ;)

Looking at your `header`, you're not including `learner_id` in the query string.

```
header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag&student_id=$student_id");
```

Change to;

```
header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag&learner_id=$student_id");
```

Comment: sorry but i dont know where to insert the codes you suggested above. i tried it many times but i cant get the right spot.

Answer (score -1):

How are you getting this `$learner_id` (using GET or POST)?

```
//if 
$learner_id=$_REQUEST['learner_id'];

$select_query="select student_id from student_information where learner_id = '$learner_id'";
$result_set = mysql_query($select_query,$link_id);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_set);
if($num_rows>0){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
    $flag="exists";
    header("location:Student_login.php?flag=$flag&student_id=$student_id");
    die();
}
else{
    mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0 ");
    if(mysql_error() != null){
        die(mysql_error());
  } 

}
```

Comment: @veducm i am using the $_POST. I tried your suggestion above and it showed me this-----> This Learner Id( ) already exists. Please try again with another Learner Id. <----                                     The notice disppeared and the close and open parenthesis left.